# BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number

Tags: go-ethereum

I created a dapp and with truffle i dployed on my private ethereum network. The network was created using geth. When i run the dapp i got an error: BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number .
[image]

contract code

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract Creation  {

    int basiclife=50;

    struct hero  { // ta periexomena enos hrwa
        string name;
        int life;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
        int attack;
        int winCount;
        int trophies;
        int lossCount;
    }
    hero[] public heroes; 


    struct enemy {  // ta periexomena enos TERATOS
        string name;
        int life;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
        int attack;
    }
    enemy[] public enemies;

  mapping (uint => address) public herotoowner;
  mapping (address => uint) public  heroCount;

  mapping (uint => address) public monstertoowner;
  uint public monsterCount; 

    function createhero(string memory _name) public  { //dhmiourgia xarakthra tou hrwa
     require(heroCount[msg.sender] == 0);
       uint id= heroes.push(hero(_name,basiclife,1,0,20,0,0,0))-1; //me name,life,lvl,xp,attack,nikes,tropaia,ites
       herotoowner[id] = msg.sender;
       heroCount[msg.sender]++;

    }
     function enemyRage(int _herolvl) public  { //dhmiourgia xarakthra tou teratos 1
       uint id=enemies.push(enemy("Rage",20*_herolvl,_herolvl,7*_herolvl,5*_herolvl))-1;
       monstertoowner[id] = msg.sender;
       monsterCount++;

    }

    function enemyDerpina(int _herolvl) public  { //dhmiourgia xarakthra tou teratos 2
       uint id=enemies.push(enemy("Derpina",40*_herolvl,_herolvl,14*_herolvl,10*_herolvl))-1; // me name,life,xp,attack
       monstertoowner[id] = msg.sender;
       monsterCount++;

    }

       function getHerosByOwner(address owner) external view returns( uint ) { //sinartisi gia euresi id kai emfanisi tou hrwa
        uint result =999999;
        for (uint i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
              if (herotoowner[i] == owner) {
                result = i;
                break;
          }
        }
        return result;
        }
        function getmonstersByOwner(address owner) external view returns( uint ) { //sinartisi gia euresi id kai emfanisi tou teratos
        uint result =0;
        for (uint i = enemies.length ; i > 0 ; i--) {
              if (monstertoowner[i] == owner) {
                result = i;
                break;
          }
        }
        return result;
        }

        uint nonce=0;

   function randNum(int _num) private   returns(int) {  //sinartisi gia tixaies times
    int randomnumber = int(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, nonce))) % _num;
    if (randomnumber <=0) {
        randomnumber=(-1)*randomnumber;
    }
    nonce++;
    return randomnumber;
    }  

    function attack_hero(uint _heroid, uint _monsterid, int _num  ) external  returns(string memory, int,int,int,int ) { // sinartisi epithesis hrwa kai teratos

      hero storage myhero = heroes[_heroid];
      enemy storage monster = enemies[_monsterid];
      int attackofhero=0;
      if(_num==0) { //se periptosi pou apotixi i apofigi tou teratos
       attackofhero=randNum(myhero.attack);
      }
      monster.life=monster.life - attackofhero;

      int attackofmonster=randNum(monster.attack);
      myhero.life=myhero.life - attackofmonster;

      if (monster.life <= 0 && myhero.life >0) { // NIki : WIN +1, anevasma xp
        myhero.winCount++;
        myhero.xp+=monster.xp;

        if (randNum(100) > 50 ){ //, pithanotita na pesi tropaio +1
              myhero.trophies++;
          }

        return("win",myhero.lvl,myhero.xp,myhero.life,myhero.trophies);
      }
      if (myhero.xp>=10+2*myhero.lvl){ // level up, lvl +1
          myhero.lvl++;
          myhero.xp=0; //reset you xp
          myhero.life=basiclife*myhero.lvl;  // epanafora zwis kai sindesis me t lvl opos kai i epithesi apo kato
          myhero.attack=myhero.attack*myhero.lvl;
        }
      if (myhero.life <= 0 ) { //ita 
          myhero.lossCount++; 
          return("dead",myhero.lossCount,myhero.life,myhero.lvl,myhero.trophies);
      } 

      return("attack",myhero.life,attackofhero,monster.life,attackofmonster);


    }
    function resurrection(uint _heroid) public { // sinartisi epanaforas zwis stin arxiki meta apo ita
         hero storage myhero = heroes[_heroid];
         myhero.life=basiclife*myhero.lvl;
     }



}
```

app.js code

```
App = {
    web3Provider: null,
    contracts: {},
    account: '0x0',
    heros: [],
    enemies: [],
    heroId: null,
    monsterId: null,
    rand: null,
    rand2: 0,
    init: function() {

        return App.initWeb3();

    },

    initWeb3: function() {
        // TODO: refactor conditional
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
            App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
            App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('locahost:8545');
            web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
        }
        return App.initContract();
    },

    initContract: function() {
        $.getJSON("Creation.json", function(Creation) {
            // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
            App.contracts.Creation = TruffleContract(Creation);
            // Connect provider to interact with contract
            App.contracts.Creation.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

            return App.render();
        });
    },
    monsterRender: function() {
        var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
        enemyspot.empty();
        if (App.rand == 1) {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;
                console.log(App.monsterId)
                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)
                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/rage.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);

            }).then(function() {
                if (App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] <= 0) {
                    alert("You have won!!!");

                    enemyspot.empty();
                }
            });
        } else {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;

                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;
                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)

                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/derpina.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);
            }).then(function() {
                if (App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] <= 0) {
                    alert("You have won!!!");
                    isCreated =0;
                    var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
                    enemyspot.empty();
                }
            });
        }
    },


    render: function() {

        // Load account data
        web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
            if (err === null) {
                App.account = account;
                $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
            }
        });
        var herospot = $("#herospot");
        herospot.empty();
        // Load contract data
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.getHerosByOwner(App.account);
        }).then(function(getHerosByOwner) {
            console.log("hey δσαδ" + getHerosByOwner)
            App.heroId = getHerosByOwner;
            console.log(App.heroId)
            return creationInstance.heroes(getHerosByOwner);
        }).then(function(heroes) {
            $("#charform").hide();
            $("#story").hide();
            console.log(account)
            App.heroes = heroes;

            var name = heroes[0];
            var life = heroes[1];
            var lvl = heroes[2];
            var xp = heroes[3];
            var atk = heroes[4];
            var winCount = heroes[5];
            var trophies = heroes[6];
            var lossCount = heroes[7];
            var heroTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/happyfa.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " +
                name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " +
                lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk + "</td></tr><tr><td>Win count</td><td>: " + winCount +
                "</td></tr><tr><td>trophies</td><td>: " + trophies + "</td></tr><tr><td>lossCount</td><td>: " + lossCount;
            herospot.append(heroTemplate);
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("hello"+App.heroes[1])
            if (App.heroes[1] <= 0) {
                console.log("sdasd" + App.heroes[1])
                alert("You have Lost!!!");
                var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
                enemyspot.empty();
                App.resurrection();
                isCreated =0;
            }
        }).then(App.loadMonsters());
    },
    fight: function() {
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance){
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.attack_hero(App.heroId, App.monsterId, App.rand2);
        }).then(function(attack_hero){
            App.monsterRender();
    App.render();
        })
    },
    resurrection:function() {

             App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance){
            creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.resurrection(App.heroId);
            }).then(function(resurrection){
                App.render();
            });
    },


    spawn: function() {
        console.log(App.heroes)
        console.log(App.account)
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
        App.rand = rand;
        var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
        enemyspot.empty();
        if (rand == 1) {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.enemyRage(App.heroes[2]);
            }).then(function(enemyRage) {
                console.log("hey1 " + enemyRage)
                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;

                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)
                App.enemies.push(enemies);
                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/rage.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);
                isCreated = 1;
            });
        } else {
            App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                creationInstance = instance;
                return creationInstance.enemyDerpina(App.heroes[2]);
            }).then(function(enemyDerpina) {
                console.log("hey1 " + enemyDerpina)
                return creationInstance.getmonstersByOwner(App.account);
            }).then(function(getmonstersByOwner) {
                App.monsterId = getmonstersByOwner;
                return creationInstance.enemies(getmonstersByOwner)
            }).then(function(enemies) {
                console.log("hey 1" + enemies)
                App.enemies.push(enemies);
                App.enemies[App.monsterId] = enemies;
                var name = enemies[0];
                var life = enemies[1];
                var lvl = enemies[2];
                var xp = enemies[3];
                var atk = enemies[4];

                var enemyTemplate = "<tr ><td colspan='2'><img src = './images/derpina.jpg' width ='200px'></td></tr><tr><td> Name</td><td>: " + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Health Points</td><td>: " + life + " HP</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>: " + lvl + "</td></tr><tr><td>Experiance</td><td>: " + xp + "</td></tr><tr><td>Attack</td><td>: " + atk;
                enemyspot.append(enemyTemplate);
                isCreated = 1;
            });
        }


    },

    validate: function() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            alert("Your name is " + name);
            return instance.createhero(name, {
                from: App.account
            });
        }).then(function(result) {

            App.render();
        });
    },
    loadMonsters: function() {
        App.contracts.Creation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            creationInstance = instance;
            return creationInstance.monsterCount();
        }).then(function(monsterCount) {
            console.log("δσφδ" + monsterCount);
            for (var i = 0; i < monsterCount; i++) {

                creationInstance.enemies(i).then(function(enemies) {
                    App.enemies.push(enemies);

                });
            }
        })
    },

};
var enemyspot = $("#enemyspot");
let startFlag;
var account;
var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
    // Check if account has changed
    if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
        account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        // Call some function to update the UI with the new account
        App.render();
        location.reload();
    }
}, 100);

function startAdventure() {
    $("#adventure").hide();
    var instructions = $("#advWrap");
    var heroT = "<p id='instructions'>Press W to walk <br> Press A to attack <br> Press R to run<p>";
    instructions.append(heroT);
   document.getElementById("#advWrap").style.color = "yellow";
    startFlag = 1;
};
let isCreated;

console.log('fasdfas' + App.monsterId)
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 87 /*&& startFlag == 1*/ ) {
        console.log("iscreated is" + isCreated)
        let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
        console.log(randomNum)
        if (randomNum == 1) {

            if (isCreated == 0 || isCreated == null || isCreated == undefined  && App.heroes[1]>0) {
                alert("You have been ambushed!!!");
                App.spawn()
                isCreated =1;


            } else if (App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] <= 0  && App.heroes[1]>0) {

                App.spawn();
                isCreated =1;
            } else if (isCreated == 1) {
                alert("You must kill this monster first")
            }
        } else if(randomNum !== 1 && isCreated !==1) {
            alert("You didn't encounter any monster");
        }else if (isCreated == 1) {
                alert("You must kill this monster first")
            }
    }
    if (e.which == 65 && isCreated == 1 && App.enemies[App.monsterId][1] > 0 && App.heroes[1]>0) {
        console.log('123       ' + App.enemies[App.monsterId][1])

        App.fight()
    }
    if (e.which == 82 && isCreated == 1) {
         App.rand2 =Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
        if (App.rand2 == 0) {
            isCreated = 0;
            enemyspot.empty();
            App.rand2 = 1;
        } else if (App.rand2 ==1 ) {
            App.fight();
        }
    }
};

$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {

        App.init();
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to restructure your question using only the relevant parts. Like at what call resulted in this error. It will be difficult for a person to go through the entire code and find the issue.

Comment: Please don't dump your entire code here, but only the part which is relevant to your question (and yes, if you're not sure which part that it then spend some time in investigating your code and finding it).

Comment: If i knew where it was the error i would not asked for help!